# Missing parameters in ionic 3 while connecting with woocommerce store

Tags: angular, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

Code is:

```
signup(){

      let customerData = {

        customer : {}
      }

      customerData.customer = {
        "email": this.newUser.email,
        "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
        "last_name": this.newUser.last_name,
        "username": this.newUser.username,
        "password": this.newUser.password,
        "billing_address": {
          "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
          "last_name": this.newUser.last_name,
          "company": "",
          "address_1": this.newUser.billing_address.address_1,
          "address_2": this.newUser.billing_address.address_2,
          "city": this.newUser.billing_address.city,
          "state": this.newUser.billing_address.state,
          "postcode": this.newUser.billing_address.postcode,
          "country": this.newUser.billing_address.country,
          "email": this.newUser.email,
          "phone": this.newUser.billing_address.phone
        },
        "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
          "last_name": this.newUser.last_name,
          "company": "",
          "address_1": this.newUser.shipping_address.address_1,
          "address_2": this.newUser.shipping_address.address_2,
          "city": this.newUser.shipping_address.city,
          "state": this.newUser.shipping_address.state,
          "postcode": this.newUser.shipping_address.postcode,
          "country": this.newUser.shipping_address.country
        }
      }

      if(this.billing_shipping_same){
        this.newUser.shipping_address = this.newUser.shipping_address;
      }

      this.WooCommerce.postAsync('customers',customerData).then( (data) => {

        let response = (JSON.parse(data.body)); 
}
}/ignore the parentheses
```

Running this code I got this error, which I can't fix:

```
{code: "rest_missing_callback_param", message: "Missing parameter(s): email, password",…}
code
:
"rest_missing_callback_param"
data
:
{status: 400, params: ["email", "password"]}
params
:
["email", "password"]
status
:
400
message
:
"Missing parameter(s): email, password"
```

Comment: I use postAsync function

Answer (score 0):

In data object, send email and password properly:

```
data: { params: { email: <email here>, password: <password here> } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Woocommerce.postAsync('customers',customerData.customer).then((data) => {
  console.log (JSON.parse(data.body));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with post function supported by your hosting web site. Typically hosting sites enforce security for post due to which at times body of post is not passed . It is better you create your own hosting server under digital ocean, AWS or GCP and follow the below steps to create a wordpress installation. Once wordpress is installed add the woocommerce plugin and enable CORS using chrome CORS plugin.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for week English, but I have also face the same problem. I do changes in a config.ts file and service.ts file.

Finally, it's working fine

Error:
 {"code":"rest_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter(s): email, password","data":{"status":400,"params":["email","password"]}}

I changed the header in the config.ts

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

and Do Some changes in the service.ts file

registerCustomer(customer) {
     var params = {
            customer: customer,
            email: customer.email,
            password: customer.password,
      };
      return new Promise(resolve => {
           this.http.post(this.config.setUrl('POST', '/wp-json/wc/v1/customers?', 
          false), params, this.config.options).map(res => 
          res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                this.user = data;
                resolve(this.user);
            }, err => {
                resolve(err.json())
            });
        });
    }

----or-----

Use this code

var options: any = {};

```
registerCustomer(customer) {
    var params = {
        customer: customer,
        email: customer.email,
        password: customer.password,
    };
    var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options.withCredentials = true;
    this.options.headers = headers;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post(this.config.setUrl('POST', '/wp-json/wc/v1/customers?', false), params, this.options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

            this.user = data;
            resolve(this.user);
        }, err => {
            alert("You are already registered with this email id !!");
            resolve(err.json())
        });
    });
}
```